# jQuery append and prepend divs and click events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to transfer the div's from one parent div to other on click of it.

Please check the below jsfiddle page for the reference

http://jsfiddle.net/fb7Tq/97/

i want to transfer the div on either side when i click on any div in grey it migrates to other div box and changes the style to red when i click back to red div it should come back to its original place in grey style.

How can i achieve this?

HTML:

```
<div class="section1">
    <div id="1" >1</div>
    <div id="2" >2</div>
    <div id="3" >3</div>
    <div id="4" >4</div>
    <div id="5" >5</div>
    <div id="6" >6</div>
    <div id="7" >7</div>
    <div id="8" >8</div>
</div>

<div class="section2"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.section1 div{height:25px; background-color:#333; color:#FFF; border:1px solid red; margin-bottom:2px; width:50px;}

.section2 div{height:25px; background-color:red; color:yellow; border:1px solid green; margin-bottom:2px; width:150px;}

.section1{float:left; margin-right:50px;}
.section2{float:left}
```

And my JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function testclick() {
        var iLoc = $(this).attr("id");
        $('.section2').append(this);
        $('#'+iLoc).unbind('click', testclick);
    }

    function testclick2() {
        alert("s");
        var iLoc = $(this).attr("id");
        $('.section1').append(this);
        this.unbind('click', testclick2);
    }
    $('.section1 div').bind('click', testclick);
    $('.section2 div').bind('click', testclick2);


});
```

Comment: Can you please include the code **within** your question as well. JsFiddle is a great tool to *complement* your question and to show a live preview of the problem, but your question should stand independently. JsFiddle is often down throughout the day, so you **massively** lower your chances of getting an answer if people can't view your code!

Comment: Thanks amaan for adding the code here, as i was disconnected from internet here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

```
$('.section1 div').bind('click', testclick);
$('.section2 div').bind('click', testclick2);
```

Into

```
$('.section1 div').live('click', testclick);
$('.section2 div').live('click', testclick2);
```

You can now remove the `.unbind()` from your functions.

**Keeping positions:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.section1 div').each(function(){
        $(this).data("pos", $(this).index());    
    });

    function testclick() {
        var node = $(this);
        var success = false;
        $('.section2 div').each(function(){
            if($(this).data("pos") > node.data("pos"))
            {
                $(this).before(node);
                success = true;
                return false;   // Jump out of loop
            }
        });

        if(!success)
        {
            $('.section2').append(node);
        }
    }

    function testclick2() {
        var node = $(this);
        var success = false;
        $('.section1 div').each(function(){
            if($(this).data("pos") > node.data("pos"))
            {
                $(this).before(node);
                success = true;
                return false;  // Jump out of loop
            }
        });

        if(!success)
        {
            $('.section1').append(node);
        }
    }
    $('.section1 div').live('click', testclick);
    $('.section2 div').live('click', testclick2);


});
```

Demo with keeping positions: http://jsfiddle.net/fb7Tq/109/

Comment: It wont work properly.We have to assign a different on click function this time.

Comment: Updated and added a demo. It does work, because the `live` function checks items within the `selection`, if the DIV is moved over, the other `live` function will take over.

Comment: great answer, it works as it is required, will implement soon in the live development environment

Answer (score 2):

Because you've got a dynamically changing DOM, **event delegation** should be screaming at you, rather than binding event handlers to the elements directly.

As a general rule, for which I can't think of an exception, if you've got a DOM that changes (e.g. via AJAX, or programatically like in your example) ***always*** use event delegation.

Change;

```
$('.section1 div').bind('click', testclick);
$('.section2 div').bind('click', testclick2);
```

To;

```
$('.section1').delegate('.section1 > div', 'click', testclick);
$('.section2').delegate('.section2 > div', 'click', testclick2);
```

You can then remove both of your `unbind()` methods in the click handlers, which leaves you [with this](http://jsfiddle.net/fb7Tq/110/);

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function testclick() {
        var iLoc = $(this).attr("id");
        $('.section2').append(this);
    }

    function testclick2() {
        alert("s");
        var iLoc = $(this).attr("id");
        $('.section1').append(this);
    }

    $('.section1').delegate('.section1 > div', 'click', testclick);
    $('.section2').delegate('.section2 > div', 'click', testclick2);

});
```

Which a) works, and b) looks a lot cleaner.

jQuery supports 2 methods of event delegation in jQuery versions before 1.7, and I *strongly* recommend you read the full documentation for both of them; yes, it's long, but it's crucial to understand the concept.

1. [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live)
2. [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate)

In jQuery 1.7 however, [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) was introduced, and both `live()` and `delegate()` are expected to be depreciated in version 1.8 (and will *eventually* be removed), because of this, you should change my use of `delegate()` in the example to;

```
    $('.section1').on('click', '.section1 > div', testclick);
    $('.section2').on('click', '.section2 > div', testclick2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

http://jsfiddle.net/fb7Tq/104/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function testclick() {
        var iLoc = $(this).attr("id");
        $('.section2').append(this);
       $('#'+iLoc).unbind('click', testclick).bind('click',testclick2) ;
    }

    function testclick2() {
       alert("s");
       var iLoc = $(this).attr("id");
       $('.section1').append(this);
       this.unbind('click', testclick2).bind('click',testclick) ;
    }
    $('.section1 div').bind('click', testclick);
    $('.section2 div').bind('click', testclick2);

});
```

Comment: This is not the best way to approach the problem; event delegation should be used.